# Android Logcat has stopped outputting Log data, not monitoring app debugging process

Tags: java, android, logcat

I have been working on an app, using the logcat for debugging, but as of today I can't get any debugging messages, but I do see a strange warning in my logcat files. The app still builds/runs fine.

```
04-18 13:55:28.700 14188-14188/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --compiler-
filter=interpret-only --debuggable
04-18 13:55:30.507 11344-11345/? E/WCNSS_FILTER: do_read: read returned 0, 
err = Success, read bytes: 0, expected: 0

                                             --------- beginning of system
04-18 13:55:31.148 14055-14055/? I/art: System.exit called, status: 0
04-18 13:55:31.384 14236-14236/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /system/app/KeyChain/lib/arm64
04-18 13:55:31.417 14236-14236/? W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the 
system process without a qualified user: 
android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1357 
android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 
android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 
com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3041 
04-18 13:55:31.502 14255-14255/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /system/priv-app/MusicFX/lib/arm64
04-18 13:55:31.740 14281-14281/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /system/priv-app/VZWAVS/lib/arm64
04-18 13:55:31.777 14304-14304/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /data/app/umn.ee4951.tola-2/lib/arm64
04-18 13:55:33.037 14461-14461/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /data/app/com.google.android.apps.gmoney-1/lib/arm64
04-18 13:55:33.130 14461-14461/? D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer 
search path /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64:/system/fake-
libs64:/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a for n 
namespace 0x7f5c01d0f0
04-18 13:55:34.180 14507-14507/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /data/app/com.google.android.apps.magazines-2/lib/arm64
04-18 13:55:34.842 14507-14546/? D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer 
search path /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64:/system/fake-
libs64:/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a for 
namespace 0x7f5bf5c0f0
04-18 13:55:34.981 14580-14580/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: 
04-18 13:55:34.985 14580-14580/? D/ApplicationLoaders: ignored Vulkan layer 
search path /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm:/system/fake-
libs:/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a for 
namespace 0xf4dd4090
04-18 13:55:35.133 14580-14580/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: 
/data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi-v7a
04-18 13:55:35.133 14580-14580/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown 
path: /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000000e/n/armeabi
```

I believe it has something to do with the error:
    W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
    /system/app/KeyChain/lib/arm64

has anyone experienced this before? Googling around yielded little help.

Comment: Do Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Yes I have. It didn't change anything.